# Why is LOX on top in the Space Shuttle external tank instead of the other the way round?

Tags: rockets, space-shuttle, fuel

Why is oxygen placed on top of hydrogen? Does this have anything to do with letting the warmer and not the colder liquid have a non-spherical bulkhead and thus more surface area to reduce boil-off?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Having the colder tank lower in the stack is marginally helpful for the thermal design, but in the case of the space shuttle, aerodynamic considerations dominate.

For [aerodynamic stability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longitudinal_static_stability), it's desirable to put the center of gravity well forward of the [center of aerodynamic pressure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Center_of_pressure_(fluid_mechanics)) (which means roughly "where the drag is happening"). Think about a throwing dart, with its heavy forward end and draggy fins at the back; the drag force on the fins keeps it from tumbling.

The wings of the space shuttle orbiter are a big source of drag, so the center of gravity needs to be forward of that. [Liquid oxygen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liquid_oxygen) is about 16 times as dense as [liquid hydrogen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liquid_hydrogen), so forward it goes, to move the overall CG forward of the wings.

Comment: It also reduces the range that the engines have to gimbal